# How to manipulate Strings in Scala while using the Play framework?

Tags: string, scala, playframework-2.2

I am using the play framework 2.2.1 and I have a question concerning the manipulation of Strings within view templates. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with the Scala programming language nor its APIs. The strings are contained in a List which is passed from the controller to the view and then I use a loop to process each string before they are added to the html. I would like to know how to do the following: trim, toLowerCase and remove spaces. As an example, if I have "My string ", I would like to produce "mystring". More specifically I would actually like to produce "myString", however I'm sure I can figure that out if someone points me in the right direction. Thanks.

UPDATE:

Fiaz provided a great solution, building on his answer and just for interest sake I came up with the following solution using recursion. This example is of course making many assumptions about the input provided.

```
@formatName(name: String) = @{  
  def inner(list: List[String], first: Boolean): String = {
    if (!list.tail.isEmpty && first) list.head + inner(list.tail, false)
    else if (!list.tail.isEmpty && !first) list.head.capitalize + inner(list.tail, false)
    else if (list.tail.isEmpty && !first) list.head.capitalize
    else list.head                  
  } 
  if (!name.trim.isEmpty) inner(name.split(' ').map(_.toLowerCase).toList, true)        
  else ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how to do just the trimming, lower-casing and joining without spaces, try this perhaps?

```
// Given that s is your string
s.split(" ").map(_.toLowerCase).mkString
```

That splits a string into an array strings, splitting is done on one or more spaces so that gives you trimmed strings. You then `map` each element in the array with the function `(x => x.toLowerCase)` (for which the shorthand is `(_.toLowerCase)`) and then join the Array back into a single string using the `mkString` method that collections have.

So let's say you want to capitalize the first letter of the each of the space-split bits:

Scala provides a `capitalize` method on Strings, so you could use that:

```
s.split(" ").map(_.toLowerCase.capitalize).mkString
```

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html

One suggestion as to how you can get the exact output (your example 'myString') you describe:

```
(s.split(" ").toList match { 
   case fst::rest => fst.toLowerCase :: rest.map(_.toLowerCase.capitalize)
   case Nil => Nil }
).mkString
```

Comment: Easy enough, appreciate the input

Answer (score 1):

There is example of using the string manipulation below:

```
@stringFormat(value: String) = @{
 value.replace("'", "\\'")
}

@optionStringFormat(description: Option[String]) = @{
  if (description.isDefined) {
      description.get.replace("'", "\\'").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
  } else {
    ""
  }
}

@for(photo <- photos) {
    <div id="photo" class="random" onclick="fadeInPhoto(@photo.id, '@photo.filename', '@stringFormat(photo.title)', '@optionStringFormat(photo.description)', '@byTags');">
```

This example obtained from https://github.com/joakim-ribier/play2-scala-gallery